# WebApi HttpPost not receiving the posted content from HttpClient

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

Web API:
I tried using [FormBody] and [FromForm] before the string stringcontent as well.

```
// POST api/<MAUserController>
        [HttpPost("AuthenticateUser")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<MAUser>> PostAsync(string stringcontent)
        {
            //stringcontent is null
        }
```

Client Code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postParameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            postParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Email", Email));
            postParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", Password));
            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postParameters);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenString);
                //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Email", Email);
                //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Password", Password);
                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(API_URL, stringContent))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
            //Success code
                    }
                    else
                    {
            //Handle unsuccessful here
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Long shot: maybe you need `API_URL + "/AuthenticateUser"` as URL?

Comment: No API_URL already has proper URI location.  The breakpoint does hit in webapi while debugging..

Comment: you're posting structured data in JSON format from the client. So why is the API just trying to accept a plain string? That doesn't make a lot of sense. Make it accept a model object with the correct structure, instead. ASP.NET will take care of binding the JSON properties to the model properties.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `([FromBody] YourModel content)`? Where `YourModel` is class with relevant properties to be deserialized from json you posting.

Comment: Also, `postParameters` should just be `postParameters  = new { Email = .., Password = .. };`

Comment: string is a value type and by default it will come from the QueryString.  Create a proper class which contains your data instead

Comment: You need to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Do you get a response?  If so what is the status?  Normal status is 200 OK or a 400/500 error.  If you do not get a response what version of TLS is in the sniffer.  Is your URL HTTP or HTTPS (Secure).   Most likely you are using TLS 1.0/1.1 which is no longer allowed and you have to upgrade to TLS 1.2/1.3.

Comment: @jdweng OP says _The breakpoint does hit in webapi while debugging._ . Nothing to do with connections or TLS. The data simply isn't binding.

Comment: @Adyson : Where is webapi in the posted code?  The TLS is automatically run with [HttpPost("AuthenticateUser")]

Comment: @jdweng Sorry but what are you on about? None of this code specifies anything about TLS. That would depend on whether the application is served over HTTPS or not. And OP has confirmed that the breakpoint is being hit, so clearly there isn't a connection problem (caused by TLS or anything else). The issue is that the incoming JSON data isn't being bound to the `string stringcontent` parameter because the two things aren't compatible as far as the ASP.NET model binder is concerned. It's a data parsing issue, not a connection issue.

Comment: @Adyson : I that is the case then the OP should have a response with a status.  Where does op say he got a response?

Comment: @jdweng I would imagine they might have stopped the debugger when they realise they didn't have any input values. Put it another way, where did the OP say they _didn't_ get a response? It's irrelevant to what's being asked about, anyway. They're not interested in that, for this question. And since my answer has been accepted, I'll assume I solved their problem. My reply to you was because it was impossible to see, from the information provided, why you'd think there would be any difficulty with the response or with something as specific as TLS issues. It's simply not part of the question.

Comment: @jdweng And also, if the connection was failing due to TLS issues, then it would fail **completely**. It would not even connect to the server - certainly the OP wouldn't be able to reach a breakpoint in the API controller, because the request would never reach the controller. The _response_ is irrelevant because there would never be a meaningful request. You're preaching about TLS issues yet you don't seem to understand how it would actually work in practice - either that or you didn't read the question and/or comments properly before adding your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're posting structured data in JSON format from the client. So why is the API just trying to accept a plain string? That doesn't make a lot of sense.

You should make it accept a model object with the correct structure, instead. ASP.NET will take care of binding the JSON properties to the model properties. However, you should also simplify the `postParameters` in the client as well - you're over-complicating the structure.

e.g.

**Client:**

```
var postParameters  = new { Email = "abc@example.com", Password = "xyz" };
```

**Server:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<MAUser>> PostAsync([FromBody] UserCredentials credentials)
{
}
```

where `UserCredentials` is a DTO class like this:

```
public class UserCredentials
{
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can my DTO class UserCredentials have more than two properties, even theoug I am posing only two parameters?  I already have a DTO object like "MAUser", that has Email, Passowrd and a other properties in that class.

Comment: If TLS fails you never get a response which means no json!!!  And no ActionResult<MAUser>

Comment: There is no TLS fail, as I do get a breakpoint hit in webapi at "PostAsync"

Comment: @WinFXGuy _"Can my DTO class UserCredentials have more than two properties, even theoug I am posing only two parameters?" ...yes absolutely. The model binder will simply ignore any properties which aren't included in the JSON, and bind the ones which are supplied.

Answer (score 0):

ok so when using content type you are basically telling the receiving API how to parse the request payload and so by telling it application/json the framework is trying to parse the payload from JSON to an object and assign it to your parameter ( not really since you need to add an attribute [FromBody] ) but it can not do it since you are expecting a string, so either change your content type or change your parameter type ( i would suggest your parameter type ) .